# Trying to get text from an url with AsyncTask and Jsoup but the text doesn't show

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup

The urls are just text files like www.example.com/example.txt so what I need to do is get the whole text from the website. The text can be very long up to 1MB. I don't know why my code does not work. When I run the code progress dialog shows up and goes away but the text is not loaded and I am not getting any errors.

Here is part of my code

```
    public class Story extends Activity {

    Elements elem = null;
    Document document;
    String url = "http://www.example.com/example.txt";
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Story.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
           document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();              
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        elem = document.select("*");
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        for (Element element : elem){
            String valueofelement = element.text();
            story.add(valueofelement);        //story is an a
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

I call it with `new Title().execute();`

Here is the LogCat

```
    11-29 17:13:07.563: D/KenBurnsView(15380): swapImage active=0
11-29 17:13:07.563: D/KenBurnsView(15380): new active=1
11-29 17:13:07.568: D/KenBurnsView(15380): starting Ken Burns animation android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator@42d5bfb8
11-29 17:13:18.103: D/AbsListView(18123): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-29 17:13:18.178: D/dalvikvm(18123): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 51K, 9% free 12366K/13447K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
11-29 17:13:18.183: I/dalvikvm-heap(18123): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.915MB for 971248-byte allocation
11-29 17:13:18.208: D/dalvikvm(18123): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 8% free 13312K/14407K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 24ms
11-29 17:13:18.233: D/dalvikvm(18123): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 13313K/14407K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
11-29 17:13:18.243: I/dalvikvm-heap(18123): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.540MB for 1705616-byte allocation
11-29 17:13:18.268: D/dalvikvm(18123): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 14978K/16135K, paused 19ms+1ms, total 28ms
11-29 17:13:18.608: D/libEGL(18123): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
11-29 17:13:18.638: D/libEGL(18123): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
11-29 17:13:18.643: D/libEGL(18123): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
11-29 17:13:18.663: D/(18123): Device driver API match
11-29 17:13:18.663: D/(18123): Device driver API version: 10
11-29 17:13:18.663: D/(18123): User space API version: 10 
11-29 17:13:18.663: D/(18123): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
11-29 17:13:18.698: D/OpenGLRenderer(18123): Enabling debug mode 0
11-29 17:13:18.953: D/KenBurnsView(18123): swapImage active=-1
11-29 17:13:19.003: D/KenBurnsView(18123): starting Ken Burns animation android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator@42d5e370
11-29 17:13:19.503: D/dalvikvm(18123): GC_CONCURRENT freed 580K, 10% free 15325K/16903K, paused 88ms+1ms, total 115ms
11-29 17:13:22.583: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18123): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
11-29 17:13:22.588: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18123): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
11-29 17:13:22.623: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18123): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
11-29 17:13:28.203: D/KenBurnsView(18123): swapImage active=1
11-29 17:13:28.203: D/KenBurnsView(18123): new active=0
11-29 17:13:28.208: D/KenBurnsView(18123): starting Ken Burns animation android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator@42e55930
11-29 17:13:37.433: D/KenBurnsView(18123): swapImage active=0
11-29 17:13:37.433: D/KenBurnsView(18123): new active=1
11-29 17:13:37.788: D/KenBurnsView(18123): starting Ken Burns animation android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator@42d5e370
```

Comment: Please don't double post questions, just update your previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Elements to get this done. It's much simpler to simply use `doc.body().ownText()` (A String) in order to get the clean, HTML-free text from a page, especially since you are only loading from a text file.

Replace `elem = document.select("*");` with `strText = document.body().ownText()`. You have to define a new String of course.

Lastly, replace the following:

```
for (Element element : elem){
    String valueofelement = element.text();
    story.add(valueofelement);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

With this:

```
story.add(strText);
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Your code should now work as intended.

Comment: Do you know a way to preserve the line breaks? I am getting one huge paragraph with this.

Comment: Use `document.body().text();` instead.

Comment: Nothing changed. Here is the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301843/how-do-i-preserve-line-and-paragraph-breaks-when-using-jsoup-to-get-text-from-an